# I make life hard for many people

Tags: riddle

I make life hard for many people,
but am important to them
once or many times in their lives.
The more I grow, my importance reduces.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Despite being intriguing, this riddle probably is too broad and admits several valid answers. Unless you add more sentences or make them more specific, this puzzle will probably be classified as "too broad".

Comment: Is it children? :-P

Comment: or maybe my wife ;-P just jokin

Comment: Are you a fart, perchance?

Answer (score 4):

> Money
>
> Not having money makes life hard for many
> It is important at many points in your life (Not so sure about this line)
> The more money you have, the less of an effect each subsequent unit of currency has on your wealth

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> darkness
>  Because there are times when a dim light can set the mood for a romantic occasion, or be useful to sneak up on an enemy during war. However, once the darkness grows too much, it becomes harder to see and accomplish any task.

Answer (score 0):

Potential answer

> age

because

> Old age makes life difficult (for many not all) but the elder you are, the less important the exact age becomes to you. On the other hand, age can be very important during many times in your life, in particular when a minimum-age is required when you're young...

Answer (score 0):

Another potential answer

> PRIDE

I make life hard for many people

> False pride makes life hard for people who wants to maintain a false status even when they cannot afford

but am important to them once or many times in their life

> They were once wealthy and proud

the more I grow my importance reduces

> People with false grown pride often lose respect.